# Logging in .NET Core to file and console - with timestamps

Tags: .net, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core, timestamp

I'm new to .NET core and didn't have the chance (yet) to dive deep into dependency injection. But I understand the concept and know that it is a good thing and also that I need it for my app. As it may be necessary to enhance or switch the logging functionality at some point.

I have started a console application that uses a class library (.net Standard 2.0) and should log stuff out to the console and also a log file.

Currently I followed some guides and configured logging with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console (nothing for file yet). The output of this logger is, that it writes two lines for each entry, like:

```
info: SampleWebConsoleApp.Program[0]
      This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.
```

I don't know about you, but I kind of dislike output for logging on two lines. My brain cannot parse this :-) . I like it on one line and with a time stamp at the beginning. As far as I found out it seems that the console logger cannot be changed to be on a single line and have a timestamp in it.

So my journey began. And I found things like Serilog, NLog or my old friend that I used in the past, log4net.

I tried to go with Serilog, because it looked simple and easy, and also it has a logger for files which I also need. So I started to throw the old console logger out and integrate the Serilog console and file logger. But then I found some examples like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .WriteTo.File("consoleapp.log")
          .CreateLogger();
        ...
}
```

But it seems to contradict my sparse knowledge of dependency injection, because I think it should be configured like this (assumption!):

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.Configure<UnknownSerilogConfigurationClass>(config => config.FileName = "consoleapp.log");
}
```

I saw someone mention, that Serilog is itself a logger factory and thus an anti-pattern to DI.

So now I am a bit confused of where to go from here.

**What logging framework that supports dependency injection should I use for a rather simple console app? Must have is, that it should me allow, to configure the output so that it includes a timestamp and the output should be on a single line.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use Log4Net also.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [NLog](https://github.com/NLog). Configuration is simple. After configuration all you need to do is inject `ILogger<T>` where `T` is the class type that uses the logger.

**nlog.config file** (don´t forget to copy it to output directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XSD manual extracted from package NLog.Schema: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema-->
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="NLog NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true" >


  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="target1" fileName="${basedir}/LogFile.txt"
            layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}" />
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="target2"
            layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message} ${exception}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="target1,target2" />    
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**.NET Core 2.2 app**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddSingleton<IFooService, FooService>()
                .AddLogging(builder =>
                {
                    builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                    builder.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions
                    {
                        CaptureMessageTemplates = true,
                        CaptureMessageProperties = true
                    });
                })
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()
                                        .CreateLogger<Program>();
            logger.LogInformation("Starting application...");

            var fooService = serviceProvider.GetService<IFooService>();
            fooService.DoWork();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**FooService**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public interface IFooService
    {
        void DoWork();
    }

    public class FooService : IFooService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public FooService(ILogger<FooService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void DoWork()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Doing work.");
        }
    }
}
```

**App output**

```
2019/03/19 23:03:44.875|INFO|Starting application... |ConsoleApp1.Program|
2019/03/19 23:03:44.920|INFO|Doing work. |ConsoleApp1.FooService|
```

Or if you don't want to use NLog or any other logging provider you can create your own [custom console logger](https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/05/05/add-custom-logging-in-aspnetcore.html) and [custom file logger](https://github.com/adams85/filelogger).

Comment: I will accept your answer as it looks like it fulfills the requirements stated by me. In the meantime I had a deeper look at Serilog and are now using it inside my project.

Comment: @Patric care to share the code you use to log to both the file and console?

Answer (score 9):

Use [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), is very simple. See [Getting Started](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started) page of library.

Install NuGet package:

```
dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.File
```

Console App sample:

```
using System;
using Serilog;

namespace SerilogExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File("logs\\logfile_yyyyDDmm.txt")
            .CreateLogger();

            Log.Information("Hello, world!");

            try
            {
                Log.Warning("Warning message..");
                Log.Debug("debug message..");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "Error message");
            }

            Log.CloseAndFlush();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output sample:

```
2021-01-28 00:09:42.123 -03:00 [INF] Hello, world!
2021-01-28 00:09:43.456 -03:00 [WRN] Debug message
2021-01-28 00:09:44.789 -03:00 [DBG] Debug message
2021-01-28 00:09:45.012 -03:00 [ERR] Error message
```